# How to read the dates on a Verpflichtungserklärung (German invitation letter)?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, iranian-citizens, invitation-letters

I am an Iranian passport holder.  My German friend sent me a *[verpflichtungserklärung](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/120691/)* from the immigration office issued in Munchen.

The date of entry has been printed:.

> From the planned day of entry on 1.5.2017 to the termination of.....

Can I get a visa that starts 3 days earlier, say 27 april or do they exactly give the visa based on the printed date?

On the second page under the part of planned length of stay nothing is printed. It is empty. I want to know if it is missing or does it have unlimited period? For some of my friends it is printed *2 monate* which is 2 months in English. 
But above that part something is printed in German: *ersetzt nicht das zustimmungsverfahren*. Does that have any special meaning about length of stay?
I want to stay with my friends for 40 days.

Comment: Please do not use bold for all of your text, use capital letters for names. Read some more of the questions to see what is the usual format here.

Comment: _Ersetzt nicht das Zustimmungsverfahren_ means that whatever that text refers to does not replace the process of agreeing first. Without seeing the whole thing I don't know what thing they are referring to, but it probably means that some agency needs to still issue some form of official consent, i. e. they need to issue  visa.

Comment: The Verpflichtungserklärung means that your friend agreed to reimburse the German state for costs related to your visit, e.g. if you get too sick to leave or if you simply refuse to leave. The form for a Verpflichtungserklärung has room for the start and end date. Possibly your friend did not give an end date.